# How can I prevent line breaks in PHP variable used as HTML email body

Tags: php, html, email

I've created a PHP script that takes the contents of an array and stuffs them into a variable called $body:

```
foreach($_POST as $var => $value)
{

    if (($var != "Submit") && ($value != "")) {

    $body .= $var .': '.filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) . '<br>';}

}
```

This $body then forms the body of an HTML email. All is fine until those contents get too long, and then I end up with an emails that sometimes lose a `<br />` (because it becomes `<b` on one line and `r />` on the next. This causes my fields to run together in the email client.

Ideas?

EDIT: I tried adding `\n` before the break, but my email client displays them
But with double quotes it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print your `"\n<br/>"`. That way you'll always get your `<BR>` in new lines.

Comment: prefix: none selected\n
required-firstname: asdf\n
mi: asfd\n
required-lastname: asfd\n
title: asdf\n
agency: safd\n
required-mailingaddress: asdf\n
My client shows the \n after each array element.

Comment: Make sure you use "\n<br>" not '\n<br>'

Comment: Alternatively, just put "\n" in $body then run nl2br($body) when you use it.  Of course, that adds readability at the expense of processing time...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to prevent the breaks, I would force them where YOU want them to be.  Figure out how long you want the line to be in characters and then create line-breaks after so many characters at a space.  This will give you more control over the layout you send in the email and the 
 will be enforced correctly.